# Multi-threading a merge sorting algorithm

Tags: java, multithreading, list, race-condition, mergesort

I have a class that does some recursive merge sorting on a generic List, as long as the element implements Comparable. I'm trying to make the code multi-threaded to improve performance, and to do this, I have a static variable `maxThreads` which keeps the number of threads I create from not exploding, and I have a static variable `currentThreads` that keeps track of the number of threads I currently have running. There seems to be a race condition on my `currentThreads` variable, but I haven't been able to come up with a solution to fix it.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadedMergeSorter<E extends Comparable<? super E>> implements, Runnable  
{
  private List<E> list;
  private List<E> left, right;
  private Thread t1, t2;
  private static final int maxThreads = 4;
  private static AtomicInteger currentThreads = new AtomicInteger(0);

  private ThreadedMergeSorter(List<E> list)
  {
    this.list = list;
  }

  public ThreadedMergeSorter(){}


  /**
   * Sorts a List<E> using the merge sorting algorithm
   * @param list the list to be merge sorted
   * @return 
   * @throws InterruptedException 
   */
  public void sort(List<E> list) 
  {
    if(list.size() > 1)
    {                  
      left = new ArrayList<E>(list.subList(0, list.size()/2));
      right = new ArrayList<E>(list.subList(list.size()/2, list.size()));

      list.clear();

      if(currentThreads.get() < maxThreads)
      {
        t1 = new Thread(new ThreadedMergeSorter<E>(left));
        t1.start();
        currentThreads.incrementAndGet();
      }
      else sort(left);

      if(currentThreads.get() < maxThreads)
      {
        t2 = new Thread(new ThreadedMergeSorter<E>(right));
        t2.start();
        currentThreads.incrementAndGet();
      }
      else sort(right);

      try{
        if(t1 != null)
        {
          t1.join();
          currentThreads.decrementAndGet();
        }
        if(t2 != null)
        {
          t2.join();
          currentThreads.decrementAndGet();
        }
      }catch(InterruptedException e){}

      list.addAll(mergeSortedLists(left, right)); 
    } 
  }

  /**
   * Merges two previously sorted List<E extends Comparable<E>> into a single List
   * @param leftArray a List of previously sorted elements
   * @param rightArray a List of previously sorted elements
   * @return an new sorted List
   */
  private List<E> mergeSortedLists(List<E> leftList, List<E> rightList)
  {
    ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();

    while(!leftList.isEmpty() && !rightList.isEmpty())
    {
      if((leftList.get(0)).compareTo(rightList.get(0)) <= 0)
        list.add(leftList.remove(0));        
      else
        list.add(rightList.remove(0));
    }

    if(!leftList.isEmpty())
      list.addAll(leftList);
    if(!rightList.isEmpty())
      list.addAll(rightList);

    return list;
  }


  @Override
  public void run() 
  {
    sort(this.list);
  }
}
```

The problem is in the `sort(List<E> list)` method by the `if` statements and the `try catch` block.

Answer (score 3):

First off, you are not running anything in parallel. Threads are started with `start()`, not `run()`, which simply calls the `run` method on the current thread.

Second, if you have shared variables being updated, try to declare them as `AtomicInteger`:

```
private static AtomicInteger currentThreads = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

Then use these methods to atomically increment/decrement:

```
currentThreads.incrementAndGet();
currentThreads.decrementAndGet();
```

Comment: This is helping. Now my code is actually finishing, but I'm still getting issues where it's decrementing my current thread count to huge negative numbers

Comment: @user1359900: Have you also added the `AtomicInteger` part?

Comment: Yes I have. I updated the code on this page to reflect the changes that I made.

Comment: @user1359900: I suggest you use an alternative approach. To the recursive call of `sort` pass another parameter indicating the level of recursion. Then set a maximum level for which you use threading, for example 2 (because at level 2 you will have 4 threads). Then when you call sort the next time call with `level + 1`. This way you can avoid all the counters and it should work ok.  If the current level is >= 2 then call sequentially. Let me know if it's clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Don't continually create, terminate and destroy threads. Don't try to micro-manage threads - it's very difficult and error-prone, as you have found out.

If you want to thread off a merge sort, (and it's not a bad idea:), look at ThreadPoolExecutor and CountDownLatch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 7 I would recommend to use the new [Fork/Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html), and use an `AtomicReferenceArray<E>` instead of a `List` so that you can do sorting in place in a thread-safe way.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (assuming you are running Java 5 and newer) can be declaring `currentThreads` as a volatile class member:

```
private static volatile int currentThreads = 0;
```

You can read more about `volatile` keyword [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/volatile-keyword-java-example-tutorial.html).

Comment: That won't solve his problem. volatile doesn't ensure atomicity, only visibility. Increments will not be atomic with volatile.